# IntelliJ won't import modules from gradle composite builds

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

UPDATE: Not only is IntelliJ having trouble, but the reason seems to be because my setup fails to build in Gradle. Still unsure why.

I'm trying to set intellij up to recognize composite gradle builds. I have Project A which depends on Project B, like this:

```
/p/projecta
/p/projectb
```

I've tried MANY things, but IntelliJ can't find the declarations of anything in `project-b` that I try to access from `project-a`. For example, in `ProjectA.java` below, IntelliJ marks the import for Project B as `Cannot resolve symbol ProjectB`

```java
// projecta/src/main/java/projecta/ProjectA.java
import projectb.ProjectB; // 'Cannot resolve symbol ProjectB'
```

```java
// projectb/src/main/java/projectb/ProjectB.java
public class ProjectB {
}
```

```
// projecta/settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'projecta'
includeBuild '../projectb'
```

```
// projectb/settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'projectb'
```

Despite the above configuration, it does not work. IntelliJ continues to mark all symbols from Project B as not resolvable.

## Other things I've tried

1. removing the includeBuild from settings.gradle, and right clicking in the gradle window on Project A, going to 'Composite Build Configuration' and adding Project B from there. Same issue.
2. Adding this code to build.gradle in Project A

```
tasks.register('run') {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('projectb').task(':run')
}
```

3. Putting Project B inside of Project A on the disk: `/p/projecta/projectb` and then changing includeBuild in projecta/settings.gradle to `includeBuild 'projectb'`
4. Many variations of #2 to try to get IntelliJ to recognize the gradle dependency.

Comment: Can you build from command line by Gradle? If one project uses another project as a dependency - you must configure it as such in build.gradle files: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies

Comment: No, it won't build from the command line, same error that intellij gives

Comment: /p/projecta/src/main/java/projecta/ProjectA.java:2: error: package projectb does not exist

import project.ProjectB;

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this problem and figured it out so I wanted to respond here so others can benefit from my foraging through the jungle of parameters and trial and error.

I have the exact same project set up as described in the question. Using Gradle 5.0, Intellij was able to correctly import and link my sources and I was able to build correctly on the command line. When I bumped the Gradle version to 5.6 and higher, Intellij was no longer able to link the sources correctly. Re-importing my project would actually work but the dependency that represents the included build would be highlighted red and the console would say that it couldn't resolve it. This happened for every Gradle version after 5.6.

It seems the root cause was Intellij was using Java 11 for Gradle while I had `sourceCompatibility` set to 10. It looks like this breaks things in more recent versions of Gradle (understandably).

I was also able to fix this by adding the following to my project's build.gradle

```
java {
    disableAutoTargetJvm()
}
```

However, I just updated my JDK for Gradle in Intellij to be Java 10 and everything worked....

Answer (score 0):

My problem was just like for @Troy, had to make all projects work under the same JDK by adding this to the build.gradle.kts:

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
    }
}
```